# An error in Phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

For last two days when i take phpmyadmin i am getting an error like this. I don't have any idea why i am getting an error like this. Anyone please help me. Thanks in advance.

**SQL query:**

```
SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8';
```

**MySQL said:**

```
[nothing]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL said 'nothing', is it error or just message?

The SET statement does not return any data sets. To check that it is working try these ones -

```
SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8';
SELECT @@character_set_client; -- should return 'utf8'

SET CHARACTER SET 'latin1';
SELECT @@character_set_client; -- should return 'latin1'
```

Answer (score 0):

You've to change the `default-character-set` operative under **[mysqld]** in Mysql configuration file. It has nothing to do about **PhpMyAdmin**. this is the default `collation` and collations are part of `mysql releases`.

> In your Mysql configuration change the default-character-set operative
>   under the [mysqld] tab. For example:
>
> ```
> [mysqld]
> default-character-set=utf8
> ```
>
> Don't forget to restart your Mysql server afterwards for the changes
>   to take effect.